# How do I call a Python function to affect a specific row in SQLite when pushing a button in HTML

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am fairly new to the world of programming. I'm attempting to build a database of active students which was added with a form. I'm now trying to add the ability to archive a child as soon as he/she's no longer active. I have attempted many different methods but I don't know how to proceed.

I added a button next to each child, and the idea is that if I click on a button that child should then be removed from the main list and added to an "archived" list, but calling a query in Python to update an active field from 1(active) to 0(inactive). I attempted to get the row ID of a specific child using jQuery, and then doing an update. One idea I read up on was to put the table inside another form and then trigger the function via POST.

I'm assuming that the only way is to do this with the student's unique ID, but getting that ID to work in the function is tricky.

```
<h1>CHILD LIST</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <section class="panel">

                <a href="/add_new_child"><button id="newChild" style="width:auto;" class="nav-item openbtn">Add a Child</button></a>
                <form action="/archive" method="post">
                    <table class="table" id="myTable2">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col style="width:50px">
                            <col style="width:150px">
                            <col style="width:150px">
                            <col style="width:150px">
                            <col style="width:150px">
                            <col style="width:150px">
                        </colgroup>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th onclick="sortTable(0)" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-snowman"></i> ID <i class="fas fa-sort"></th>
                                <th onclick="sortTable(1)" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-snowman"></i> NAME <i class="fas fa-sort tooFar"></i></th>
                                <th onclick="sortTable(2)" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-snowman"></i> SURNAME <i class="fas fa-sort tooFar"></th>
                                <th onclick="sortTable(3)" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-snowman"></i> PARENT <i class="fas fa-sort tooFar"></th>
                                <th onclick="sortTable(4)" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-snowman"></i> SCHOOL <i class="fas fa-sort tooFar"></th>
                                <th scope="col"><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i><i class="fas fa-snowman"></i> ACTION</th>

                            </tr>

                            {% for row in childData %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                                <td class="pdata">{{ row.childName }}</td>
                                <td class="pdata">{{ row.childSurname }}</td>
                                <td class="pdata">{{ row.parentName }}</td>
                                <td class="pdata">{{ row.schoolName }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger" name="inactive" href="#" ng-click="archiveChild({{ row.id }})" disabled><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <script>
    $('tr').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.btn-danger').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    function archiveChild(child)
    {
        alert(child);
        $('.btn-danger').click(function(){

        // python function call
        $.post("/child/10")
            .done(function (reply)
            {
                $('tr.selected').remove();
                $('.btn-danger').attr('disabled','disabled');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
             });
        });
    }

</script>
```

```
@app.route("/" , methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():
    """Show Child data"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        db.execute("UPDATE childData SET active = 0 WHERE childData.id=:rowid",
                   rowid=request.form['rowid'])

    # Select the necessary data to view from Child Data, Parent data and school data
    childData = db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT childData.id, childData.childName, childData.childSurname, childData.fees, parentData.parentName, schoolData.schoolName, schoolData.contactName FROM childData, parentData, schoolData WHERE childData.parentID = parentData.parentID AND childData.schoolID = schoolData.schoolID AND childData.userID=:userID AND parentData.userID=:userID AND schoolData.userID=:userID AND childData.active = 1",
                          userID=session["user_id"])

    return render_template("index.html", childData=childData)
```

```
@app.route("/child/<id>" , methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def archive_child(id):
    """archive Child data"""

    db.execute("UPDATE childData SET active = 0 WHERE childData.id = :childId",
          childId=id)

    return '1'
```

All the students with active 1 is on one list and 0 is on another. A button must then change the active value of any student I choose from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.

Comment: I did some further research and added some code snippets that will hopefully show the direction I'm trying to go with this.